# Adding additional information to Wire-Tapped Channels for logging in Spring

Tags: spring-integration

I'm using Wire-Tap to handle logging and I'm not allowed to use logging-channel-adapter (hence log4j).

I've the need to add additional informations to the payload that get sent to a gateway that has an interface that handles logs.

Is there a way without specifying a header-enricher in the middle of the flow?

Code for clarification:

The Wire-Tap part

```
<int:channel id="IN_messageRouterFactory">
    <int:interceptors>
        <int:wire-tap channel="IN_log_gateway" />
    </int:interceptors>
</int:channel>
```

The logging gateway:

```
<int:gateway service-interface="foo.bar.loginterface">
    <int:method name="log" request-channel="IN_log_gateway" />
</int:gateway>
```

The logging service:

```
<int:chain input-channel="IN_log_gateway">
        <!-- transformations here... -->
    <int:service-activator ref="fileLoggerService"/>
</int:chain>
```

I would like to add some informations so that I could log specific managed payload informations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the big height it isn't clear what you ask for. But anyway any POJO service can accept `Message<?>` as an argument. Hence you have any information (`payload` and `headers`) to do any logic.

From here I don't see reason to have `<gateway>`, since WireTap is a one-way component, so your custom `logger` should not return any result.

**UPDATE**

Thanks for the explanation.

Looks like it would be better to do that with some message enrichement (like you said `header-enricher`), because you really have a `message scope` logic.

Of course, you can overcome that with `wire-tap`, but you must have an `aggregator` to `correlate` and `group` request and its reply. And again: you can't achieve that without `header-enricher`.

BTW you can even store request message in the header and use it in your last `<service-activator>` to get the proper business logic.

Comment: Hello, thanks for answering and sorry if my question has been somewhat confusing.

I'll try with an example:

I'd like to log the beginning and the end of a chain (that has a transformer and a service-activator + error checking router).
This chain has a logical meaning: let's say that this chain's purporse is "ask for a Number to a web service".

So, what I'm looking for is a way to wire-tap the input and output channel of the chain and adding (without specifying anyother component like a header-enricher) the logical purpose of the chain + chain's outcome (fail or success).

Comment: Added more info to the answer according to your comment

Comment: I'm discussing this with my colleagues, meanwhile: thanks! :)

Comment: They (I had other tasks to solve, so they took over me on this feature) told me they resolved with spring AOP, logging AROUND the function wrapping the functionality (I hope I got it right... I'm still new to AOP!) ... thanks!

Comment: That's good too, if you've achieved a desired result. Anyway, if my answer is relevant, let's accept it to have a finished discussion.